# Как создать базу данных Room, где одно поле предварительно заполнено, а во второе приходят данные из интернета

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-room, android-sqlite

Есть база данных, с возможностью предварительного заполнения:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Schedule::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun scheduleDao(): ScheduleDao

    companion object { // аналог static в java
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "app_database")
                    .createFromAsset("database/bus_schedule.db")
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance

                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Есть база данных, для заполнения с помощью Retrofit:

```
@Database(entities = [CardModel::class, MedicationsModel::class], version = 1)
abstract class DBPharmacy : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val cardDao: CardDao
    abstract val medicationsDao: MedicationsDao
}
```

Мне нужно сделать что-то среднее, чтобы первое поле было предварительно заполнено, а во второе можно было записывать данные, приходящие из интернета

Comment: Не вполне понятна суть ваших затруднений. Если вы ищите какое-то готовое решение - то его нет. Надо просто вручную написать код, который базу данных заполнит данными. Из файла или из сети - уже не очень важно.

Comment: Заготавливаете базу с двумя полями - одно заполнено, другое пустое. После получения данных из сети заполняете второе поле.